# How to set background image position and gradient position independently?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a big image that contains 4 little images. I want to set position for image only like 4px 4px to show first little image, but it is also used for the gradient background. How to set background image position and gradient position independently?

```
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-position: 4px 4px;
```

I tried to use this variant:

```
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), 4px 4px, -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), 4px 4px, -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), 4px 4px, -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), 4px 4px, -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
```

or this:

```
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(4px 4px, #FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(4px 4px, #FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -o-linear-gradient(4px 4px, #FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-image: url('../big_image.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(4px 4px, #FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different `background-position` for both your `background-image` and the `background-gradient` by separating them using a comma.

Also, specify your `background-image` and the `background-gradient` using the `background` property instead of `background-image`.

This should work perfecly:

```
background: url('../big_image.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background: url('../big_image.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background: url('../big_image.png'), -o-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background: url('../big_image.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #ECECEC);
background-position: 4px 4px, 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you gotta use Z-index in CSS.
1st, you make a div wich contains the bg images and their position.
2nd you make another div with gradients and their position too.
then you set each z-index as you desire, if gradients stay behind the images, z-index for gradients is less than the images one